# Disabled play, next track, previous track buttons on now playing info on notification screen

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Play, next track, previous track buttons gets disabled when I start play a music track after `AVPlayerViewController` finished showing video.
Reproduction steps:

- start music track on `AVPlayer`
- pause music track on `AVPlayer`
- start showing video on `AVPlayerViewController` with different `AVPlayer`
- close `AVPlayerViewController`
- start (unpause) music track on `AVPlayer`
- show notification screen

And I see that button are disabled.

[image]

I want to have enabled buttons rather than disabled. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show some code

Comment: What exact part do you want to see? There is a lot of code. It hard to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

After video is finished you should update `nowPlayingInfo` in `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`

Comment: I update `nowPlayingInfo` in `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` when I unpause a music track, after close `AVPlayerViewController`. It doesn't help.

Comment: Validate that AVPlayer is working and you set all fields to nowPlayingInfo

Comment: "Validate that AVPlayer is working" - 
Do you mean AVPlayer is playing? yes when I unpause player it is playing.

"you set all fields to nowPlayingInfo" - 
Why should I set all fields? For instance I don't need to set `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream` field, so I don't set that field. There is no sense to set all fields.

Comment: Sorry for my answer, I'll try to extend what I mean. Could you please verify that you set up MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime, MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate? I also suggest to verify commands(playCommand: MPRemoteCommand, nextCommand: MPRemoteCommand and etc) are enabled in MPRemoteCommandCenter

Comment: I verified all that you pointed, but result the same

Comment: Have you verified commands after you unpaused track?

Comment: I've added temporary code it in KVO method `observeValue(forKeyPath...` for property `timeControlStatus` of `AVPlayer`. When property `timeControlStatus` is changed I set up `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime`, `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration`, `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` and enable playCommand, nextCommand, previousCommand

Comment: Hello, I got the same issue and realize that the now playing info center does not look the same on iOS 12, 13, 14. Did you find a solution since ?